# Javascript Postfix Math

Tags: javascript, evaluation, postfix-notation

I ran into a little bit of a problem regarding the speed of a program, and I wondered how to solve it. I’m accepting a user input equation in the form of:

```
"y = 3*x^2 - 2*x"
```

For brevity, I will work with this example. After converting it into postfix, I get:

```
[ 3, x, 2, ^, *, 2, x, *, - ]
```

So then if I wanted to graph this, I just simply make an array of x values and find the corresponding y values for my line to pass through. However, the function will evaluate much more quickly (which is crucial to make animated graphics), if I could take this user input and turn it into a function such as:

```
function userExpression( x ){
  return 3*Math.pow(x,2)-2*x
}
```

Is there any way to convert this string into a function for faster evaluation. I am well aware of the fact that I can just parse the postfix expression I’ve made and It will work, but I’m fairly sure this is going to become a pretty bad bottleneck, especially if I’m working with a 3D graph.

I had the idea to inject html with a `script` tag into the page, but I’d like to hear what others would do in this situation. Also, I’d be interested to hear how you’d do it in other languages such as C or C++, Python, anything really.

Comment: I'm lost as to what actual problem you're trying to solve.  Is this a question about performance or a question about how to parse a text equation and turning it into a function.

Comment: "I'm fairly sure this is going to become a pretty bad bottleneck"  Try it first and see if it causes performance problems.  Avoid premature optimization.

Comment: @phari I did try it and does work! This is not premature optimisation, this is an important optimisation to avoid calling a postfix parser thousands of times per frame.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've already parsed the string, I want to know how I'd go about evaluating it as a function, rather than using a post script evaluator.

Comment: Since it looks like you may be new here - in the future you'll get more people participating in answering if you don't disappear for 45 minutes when people are asking you to clarify your question.  You really ought to post the question and then monitor it for the next 10-15 minutes to see if everyone who reads it understood it.  The majority of people will see your question while it's fresh (in the first 30 minutes) and if it isn't entirely clear what you're asking, you will miss a lot of people that could help and offer you potentially unique and helpful answers.

Comment: I appreciate that @jfriend00 I'll be sure to do that the next time I post. Thanks again :)

Comment: @user2662833: You're not supposed to run the *parser* thousands of times, only the evaluator. Which should be rather fast actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already figured out how to parse the expression and generate the requisite Javascript as a string, then you can optimize performance by creating a compiled function using the `Function` constructor:

```js
var expression = "return 3 * Math.pow(x, 2) - 2 * x;";
var func = new Function("x", expression);

snippet.log(func(-2));
snippet.log(func(-1));
snippet.log(func(0));
snippet.log(func(1));
snippet.log(func(2));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Bear in mind the all usual caveats regarding `eval()` because this really isn't all that different, though it should be more performant than `eval()` because the function is compiled in the global scope.

Comment: If I've already parsed the string to postfix, is there going to be any other unforeseen problem? I've never used eval because it gets so much hate :P

Comment: @user2662833 You just need to be careful to make sure that the user can't include any malicious code in the formula. If your parsing algorithm only permits numbers and known operators, and variable names, then you're probably in good shape.